# Match Columns in different sheets and Update column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, multiple-columns

I have an Excel Workbook in which I've got a `DataEntry` sheet and lot of other sheets. What I have to do is on basis of columns (at least 2) matching between `DataEntry` sheet and `Sheet1`, I want to pick value of the third column of `DataEntry` sheet and insert it in matching a row of `Sheet1` in the corresponding column.

My data looks like this:

**`DataEntry` sheet**

```
     A          B        C
+----------+--------+---------+  
| Roll No  |  Name  |  Marks  |    
+----------+--------+---------+  
| 101      |  abc   |  45     |  
| 102      |  def   |  25     |  
| 103      |  ghi   |  65     |  
| ...      |  ...   |  ..     |  
| 201      |  ijk   |  45     |  
| 202      |  lmn   |  35     |  
| 203      |  opq   |  65     |  
| ...      |  ...   |  ..     |  
| 301      |  rst   |  15     |  
| 302      |  uvw   |  57     |  
| 303      |  xyz   |  48     |    
| ...      |  ...   |  ..     |    
+----------+--------+---------+
```

**`11-Green-English` sheet**

```
     A          B        C
+----------+--------+---------+  
| Roll No  |  Name  |  Marks  |    
+----------+--------+---------+  
| 101      |  abc   |  --     |  
| 102      |  def   |  --     |  
| 103      |  ghi   |  --     |  
| ...      |  ...   |  ..     |    
+----------+--------+---------+
```

**`11-Blue-English` sheet**

```
     A          B        C
+----------+--------+---------+  
| Roll No  |  Name  |  Marks  |    
+----------+--------+---------+  
| 201      |  ijk   |  --     |  
| 202      |  lmn   |  --     |  
| 203      |  opq   |  --     |  
| ...      |  ...   |  ..     |    
+----------+--------+---------+
```

**`11-White-English` sheet**

```
     A          B        C
+----------+--------+---------+  
| Roll No  |  Name  |  Marks  |    
+----------+--------+---------+  
| 301      |  rst   |  --     |  
| 302      |  uvw   |  --     |  
| 303      |  xyz   |  --     |    
| ...      |  ...   |  ..     |    
+----------+--------+---------+
```

I want to enter the data into `DataEntry` sheet and update `11-Green-English` sheet, `11-Blue-English` sheet, `11-White-English` sheet and similar sheets like these.

I tried the following function but it doesn't work for a lot of sheets:

```
Sub update()
    Dim cell1, cell2, col1, col2 As Range

    For Each cell1 In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
    If IsEmpty(cell1.Value) Then Exit For
        For Each cell2 In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
            If IsEmpty(cell2.Value) Then Exit For
            If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(cell1.Row, 2) = _
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cell2.Row, 2)
            End If
        Next cell2
    Next cell1
End Sub
```

However, I tried the following Excel formula but it doesn't work for more than 1 sheets:

```
=INDEX('DataEntry-Group-A'!C:C, MATCH(A4&B4, '11-Urdu-G'!A:A&'11-Urdu-G'!B:B, 0))
```

Comment: Please see [help/on-topic].  Quote: "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them..."

Comment: @ashleedawg No matter if you can provide the solution in any way

Comment: We like to see that you've at least _tried_ to solve the issue on your own.  This isn't a "free development service", this is programmers helping programmers.  Please see [mcve] as well as [ask].

Comment: @ashleedawg I've provided the code

Comment: (+ for the edit!)... so you want to enter data and have different sheets populate for each `Roll No`, correct?

Comment: @ashleedawg yeah you are right; different sheets populate for each combination of `Roll No` and `Name`

Comment: @ashleedawg are you looking at to provide some solution

Comment: So, your code (in  your question) works fine for populating one sheet,correct?

Comment: @ashleedawg Yeah and the formula also working for only one sheet